# Why is there spacing?

Tags: html, css

I have this annoying little bit of spacing I can't remove.

Here's a [fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/MichaelT/QzYcf/)

It's the white padding(?) between the dog and grey box.

I should probably mention I'm in the process of learning about the box model (relative/absolute) etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

use `display: block;` on your img http://jsfiddle.net/QzYcf/1/

Answer (score 1):

```
#header img { width: 100%; display: block; border: none;}
```

Comment: I spent a stint as an email developer.  Some mail clients would insert a phantom border unless you explicitly set the border to none.  It's just habit I guess, and probably completely unnecessary outside of a world where you don't have to deal with outlook and hotmail.

Answer (score 0):

Move the wrapper div to encase all the divs. Like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djp122/QzYcf/14/)

You what the header like this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/djp122/QzYcf/34/) right

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="outer">
       <div id="inner"></div>
</div></div>
<div id="header">
    <img src="http://davesizer.com/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2010/03/eva_jump.jpg" alt="Dog">
</div>
```

Change this #wrapper and #header to this:

```
#wrapper{
  position: relative; /*or position: absolute; top: 250px;*/
  top: 240px;
  width:100%;
  background-color: lightgrey;
 }


#header{
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height:auto;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

Comment: the header is going to be a stick image. By that I mean the wrapper is going to overlay the header on scroll. So I need to package  it all together.

Comment: Do you mean a fixed image? Where the header stay on top not matter the scroll position?

Comment: sorry no – I'll either fix the header then on scroll the wrapper overlays the header. Like this in someways: http://fearthegrizzly.com/ (minus the fade).

Comment: Check out the new answer with fiddle.